# Gui trouble with button layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm attempting use flow layout to make a menu screen that orients with a single column, but whenever I add a button, it adds it to a single row.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Proj 
{
    JPanel card1,card2; 
    ActionListener listener;
    JFrame menu;
    JFrame catagories;
    JButton menu1,addOrTake,cata,payd,showd;
    //JButton 
    public Proj(){


        card2=new JPanel();


        menu = new JFrame("Card Layout");
        catagories = new JFrame();

        //final Container contentPane = menu.getContentPane();
        final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
        menu.setLayout(layout);
        card1=new JPanel();

        menu1 = new JButton("");
        menu1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/sabar/Menu.jpg"));
        menu1.setSize(60,600);
        menu1.setVisible(true);

        addOrTake = new JButton();
        addOrTake.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample       Pictures/Penguins.jpg"));

        cata = new JButton("");
        cata.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Penguins.jpg"));

        showd = new JButton("");
        showd.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Penguins.jpg"));

        payd = new JButton("");
        payd.setSize(60, 600);
        payd.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Penguins.jpg"));
        payd.setVisible(true);

        card1.add(menu1);
        card1.add(addOrTake);
        card1.add(cata);
        card1.add(showd);
        card1.add(payd);

        menu1.addActionListener(listener);
        addOrTake.addActionListener(listener);
        cata.addActionListener(listener);
        showd.addActionListener(listener);
        payd.addActionListener(listener);

        listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {}};
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            menu.setSize(60, 600);
            menu.setVisible(true);
            JButton poo=new JButton("Poo");
            poo.setSize(60,600);
            card2.add((poo));
            card2.add(new JButton("Pee"));
            card2.add(new JButton("Per"));
            card2.add(new JButton("POt"));
            card2.setVisible(false);
            menu.add(card2);

            menu.add(card1);
            catagories.pack();
            menu.pack();
            card1.setVisible(false);


    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Proj poop =new Proj();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a `GridBagLayout` instead

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- You're adding components to menu, the CardLayout-using container, without use of a 2nd parameter String constant. Without this, it might be hard to easily swap "cards" (components).
- If you want a single column type of layout, you need to use a layout manager that allows this, and the JPanel default layout isn't it. Better options:

  - GridLayout(0, 1) for variable number of rows, one column
  - BoxLayout(Container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)
  - GridBagLayout with the right GridBagConstraint gridx and gridy attributes.

Comment: I'm fairly new to java. Is it possible to do both cardlayout and gridlayout? I need to switch between menu screens.

Comment: @KenM: of course. Simply use GridLayout in one of the "card" JPanels, and add it to the CardLayout using JPanel. But your question and code tell us that you haven't read the layout manager tutorial at all, and you want to do this first.

Comment: @KenM Each layout would be responsible for an individual container, so the `CardLayout` would take care of the `card1` and `card2` components and the `GridBagLayout` would take care of the buttons

Answer (score 1):

Start by using a layout manager which is capable of achiving your results.

Start by taking a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for some ideas.

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Proj {

    JPanel card1, card2;
    ActionListener listener;
    JButton menu1, addOrTake, cata, payd, showd;
    //JButton 

    JFrame menu;

    public Proj() {

        menu = new JFrame("Card Layout");

        //final Container contentPane = menu.getContentPane();
        final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
        menu.setLayout(layout);
        card1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        card2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        menu1 = new JButton("Mneu");
        menu1.setVisible(true);

        addOrTake = new JButton("Add or take");
        cata = new JButton("Cata");
        showd = new JButton("ShowD");
        payd = new JButton("payd");

        card1.add(menu1, gbc);
        card1.add(addOrTake, gbc);
        card1.add(cata, gbc);
        card1.add(showd, gbc);
        card1.add(payd, gbc);

        menu1.addActionListener(listener);
        addOrTake.addActionListener(listener);
        cata.addActionListener(listener);
        showd.addActionListener(listener);
        payd.addActionListener(listener);

        listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        };
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JButton poo = new JButton("Poo");
        card2.add((poo), gbc);
        card2.add(new JButton("Pee"), gbc);
        card2.add(new JButton("Per"), gbc);
        card2.add(new JButton("POt"), gbc);

        menu.add(card2, "Card2");
        menu.add(card1, "Card1");

        layout.show(menu.getContentPane(), "Card1");

        menu.pack();
        menu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        menu.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Proj poop = new Proj();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'd also have a closer look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details about how it works, because you're using it wrong

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. I'm on my way to fixing it now :)